# How to iterate through a tuple array with for loop in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples

I have an array of tuples defined as:

```
var points2D:Array=[(1,1),(2,3),(4,3),(9,5),(3,3),(7,6),(5,6)]
```

when trying to go through it like this:

```
func foo(){
    for (x,y) in points2D{
    }
}
```

I get this error message:

```
'τ_0_0' is not convertible to '(@lvalue Array, @lvalue Array)'
```

What does it mean, and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If that's your actual code nothing seems wrong...

Comment: Don't know if it is relevant, it is inside a playground and the full error message is:
cannot assign value of type 'Array<_>' to type 'Array'/var/folders/04/3c4h144j2cngl5c48p6ms7y40hdhk0/T/./lldb/7684/playground520.swift:33:22: error: 'τ_0_0' is not convertible to '(@lvalue Array, @lvalue Array)'
        for (x,y) in points2D{

Comment: Doesn't look like the code is the problem. I also tested it in a playground and it works.

Comment: Looks like your playground is corrupted or something; `type Array/var/folders...` = no bueno.

Comment: I created a new playground, wrote the same code it still presented the error. I actually have the for inside a function, I'll edit the question.

Comment: Moving the array into the function removes the error, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Have you declared `point2D` twice? I get the error if I have a second variable called like it, but of course, then I also get: `error: invalid redeclaration of 'points2D'`

Comment: No it is declared only once and I don't get the error: invalid redeclaration of 'points2D'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of points2D is not `Array`, but rather `Array<(Int,Int)>`,
so let Swift infer the type:

```
 var points2D = [(1,1),(2,3),(4,3),(9,5),(3,3),(7,6),(5,6)]
```

or set the correct type explicitly:

```
var points2D:Array<(Int,Int)> = [(1,1),(2,3),(4,3),(9,5),(3,3),(7,6),(5,6)]
```

Comment: It works! But what is the difference when I move it inside the function? Why the definition as just an Array enough inside the same function scope? And why doesn't it infer the <(Int,Int)> when declared in different scopes?

Comment: I'd also like to know why it worked in all our playgrounds (see question comments) but not the OP's.

Comment: @LeonardoMarques Note that your code works for me in the playground. I can't say I've read somewhere in the docs about this behaviour (I might missed something though). So I tested this in a real project, and it didn't worked, so I've made my answer based on that.

Comment: @TroyT Can't really say why it works for us, and not for OP. It could be that something is wrong with his playground, or the issue is related to Xcode's version ...